# SVN 1.7.1 Issue

Tags: linux, windows, svn, netbeans, ubersvn

I have just upgraded to SVN 1.7.1 and I have had nothing but problems trying to get my netbeans and everything else to work with it. I have tried 'svn upgrade' but I get an error which is as follows:

> C:\wamp\Projects>svn upgrade BMPortal
>
> svn: E155019: Can't upgrade 'C:\wamp\Projects\BMPortal' as it is not a
>   pre-1.7 working copy directory
>   svn: E150000: Missing default entry

Could anyone suggest a way to fix this. The reason why I am trying to upgrade is because my netbeans says:

> The Path 'C:\wamp\Projects\BMPortal' appears to be part of a
>   Subversion 1.7 or greater working copy. Please upgrade your Subversion
>   client to use this working copy.

As I have upgraded my SVN Client to 1.7, I don't know why it is still moaning at me.

**Just FYI:**

The SVN Server is on an Arch Linux box running UberSVN.
The client (my computer) is Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN v1.7.0 and above uses a new working copy file format, so you need to upgrade your working copy to the new format.  If you right-click the folder in Windows Explorer, the TortoiseSVN context menu items should show only "SVN Upgrade working copy" - click that to upgrade it.

Warning: If you use any other SVN apps as well as TortoiseSVN on the same PC, they may not work with the new working copy file format.

It's worth upgrading in my opinion though - must faster, better merging, better dialogs and error reporting, etc!

Comment: Sorry, misread your question - the error you're getting appears to say that your working copy is *already* in the v1.7 file format...

Comment: Okay so if my working copy is already 1.7 then why does it say I need to upgrade my svn client? Im just so confused now ¬_¬

Comment: Could it be that your netbeans can't communicate to the newer Tortoise?  Is there a newer version of netbeans you could try?

Comment: I'm reinstalling NetBeans now, It's not the best solution, I don't like having to reinstall things, but oh well. i'm sure It's not the end of the world. I'll let you know how it goes

Answer (score 5):

I actually had the very same problem (or at least the same error message!).
After trying everything you have said earlier and not getting any results, I realise that I had copied some files to the project that contains svn files from an older (1.6) version. I delete the 1.6 folders and the everything worked fine again.

I hope this could help some other people too!

Best regards,
Andrés

Comment: how did you find the old folders?

Answer (score 3):

Your Netbeans installation seems to use another SVN-Client as the one when you type `svn` on the console.

So you have to upgrade your Netbeans-Subversion plugin too.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was a mixture between yours and the above post that helped! If I could accept two I'd accept your post as well ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to waste your time guys, I have finally found a work around for this, http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Subversion1_7

But thanks again all the same! It's much appreciated!